# Is condition chaining possible in awk?

Tags: awk, conditional-statements, chaining

Input file has in $1 two names. $2 is mostly filled but sometimes empty.

```
    1;   2;    3; 
Trump;  abc;
Obama;  
Obama;  abc;
Obama;  
Trump;  abc;
```

I am looking for a condition in AWK that fills $3 with the word "media" if name "Trump" or "Obama" occurs in $1 and $2 is emtpty.

I tried:

```
{if ($1=="Trump" || $1=="Obama" && $2==" ") {$3=="Media"};
print $0}
```

and

```
{if ($1=="Trump" && $2==" ") {$3=="Media"};
if ($1=="Obama" && $2==" ") {$3=="Media"};
print $0}
```

Comment: can you show the exemplary line with empty $7 field?

Comment: ehm is this better?

Comment: You seem to be really struggling with how to ask a question. It's extremely simple - read [ask] and then just post concise, testable, sample input and the output you want to get from that input plus what you've tried so far. Posting sample input with 3 fields and asking how to operate on the 7th field, some of the text you want to operate on (`media`) completely absent from the sample input, no expected output and 2 disconnected parts of scripts is not helpful - it's nothing but confusing.

Comment: As @EdMorton comented, please provide a [mcve] so we can understand what is your problem.

Comment: you're not checking `$7` for null but for one space, with default field separator this cannot happen, also you're not setting `$13`, (why not `$3`) but comparing with "Media" in your second snipplet

Comment: I am trying to be more concise and check my posts before I make them public no matter what.

Comment: Conciseness is brevity with clarity. You're making your posts brief, not concise. The clarity is missing.

Comment: @EdMorton: _Conciseness is brevity with clarity_ Now you've done saying it :D. My google returns no results for that soon.to-be-the quote <3.

Comment: @JamesBrown Don't blame/credit me :-), that's just what conciseness means. See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concise and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conciseness. Something I think you could blame me for (since I hadn't come across anyone else using it before I started using it in presentations) is the claim that all software has 4 absolutely fundamental "C" considerations like a diamond does (diamond="Cut, Color, Carat, Clarity" while software="Conciseness, Consistency, Cohesion, Coupling) and it's important to note that brevity alone is not desirable but conciseness is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that field separator is `\t`(tab) and each second field which is empty contains space `" "`(whitespace) you may use the following approach:

```
awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"; if($1~/Trump|Obama/ && $2~/ /)$3="media"; print}' testfile
```

`$1~/Trump|Obama/` - checks field value against regular expression

---

The output:

```
Trump   abc
Obama           media
Obama   abc
Obama           media
Trump   abc
```

---

*Alternative comparisons for second field:*

`$2!~/[^ ]/`

`$2~/[[:space:]]/` - POSIX class for whitespace characters

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about  checking field values against regular expressions and that an empty field equals the reg.exp. / /

Comment: Something is still wrong:            If I check $2~/  / for emptyness it does not work consistently. In my case it worked only for the second time conditon was true?!             If I check againg  $2~/abc/ it always works as you said. So there is an isse with regex looking for empty field..

Comment: @EdMorton, I don't understand you

Comment: @EdMorton, I'm from Ukraine. We have our issues, problems, "facts" and we have to build our own way. Against that backdrop, Trump's "alternative facts" aren't important